# Can I use Disk, Network Interface and Network Security Group while creating the VM in Azure?

Tags: azure

Before creating the VM on Azure, I created a *Disk*, a *Network Interface* and a *Network Security Group*.

While creating the VM, I didn’t find options so that I can use *Disk*, *Network Interface* and *Network Security Group* that I created before creating the VM. And once the VM was ready, it has own *Disk*, *Network Interface* and *Network Security Group*.

Can I use *Disk*, *Network Interface* and *Network Security Group* while creating the VM?

If yes, let me know, how?

With Regards
Techie

Comment: as far as the disk, you can do this: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/create-vm-specialized-portal#create-a-vm-from-a-disk and you should be able to select the vnet and NSG. you may need to use an ARM or Bicep template for the NIC though.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, you can select/add all of these as you work through the portal to create the VM